# Rails link to help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my routes:

```
match '/:kategoris/:id' => 'konkurrancers#show', :as => 'konkurrance'
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
```

I am using friendly url.

My routes works perfectly.

The problem is it dont know how I link to them:

I have tried this in my root view:

```
<% @konkurrencer.each do |vind| %>
<li><%= vind.name %></li>
<li><%= link to "vind.name", konkurrance_path(vind.cached_slug) %></li>
 <% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"konkurrancers", :action=>"show", :kategoris=>"horoskoptesten-hvad-siger-stjernerne-om-dig"

horoskoptesten-hvad-siger-stjernerne-om-dig is a konkurrance
```

Instead I would like the link to be:
{:controller=>"konkurrancers", :action=>"show", :kategoris => "vind-rejse" :id=>"horoskoptesten-hvad-siger-stjernerne-om-dig">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass in 2 paarmeters when you use link to.

`<li><%= link to "vind.name", konkurrance_path(vind.name,vind.cached_slug) %></li>`

Comment: <li><%= link_to vind.name, konkurrance_path(vind.kategori.cached_slug, vind.cached_slug) %></li>

Answer (score 0):

Run "rake routes" to display the details of all of your current routes.